# Why this exception with mvn exec plugin but not with bare java command

Tags: java, maven

My dependencies in the POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jcef</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcef</artifactId>
  <version>3.1750</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jogl-all</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
  <artifactId>gluegen-rt</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I always compile with `mvn compile`. Then if I execute with mvn exec plugin:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.MyApp"
```

it throws and Exception (i.e. `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.cef.network.CefRequest_N`).

But everything works fine if I do manually:

```
java -cp "path_to_repo/org/jcef/jcef/3.1750/jcef-3.1750.jar:./target/classes:path_to_repo/org/jogamp/gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.1.4/gluegen-rt-2.1.4.jar:path_to_repo/org/jogamp/jogl/jogl-all/2.1.4/jogl-all-2.1.4.jar" com.example.MyApp
```

I debugged mvn exec with -X option, showing what I was expecting:

```
[DEBUG] com.example:myapp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT (selected for null)
[DEBUG]   org.jcef:jcef:jar:3.1750:compile (selected for compile)
[DEBUG]   org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:jar:2.1.4:compile (selected for compile)
[DEBUG]   org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:jar:2.1.4:compile (selected for compile)
```

which is the same I include manually.

It seems like the maven exec plugin is doing something different that causes the crash. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the classpathScope variable to `compile` - since version 1.1.2 the default scope seems to be `runtime`:
See the [exec-maven-plugin documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) for more information.

Comment: I've just tried that, including `<exec.classpathScope>compile</exec.classpathScope>` inside `properties` in my POM, but I've got the same result. Thank you.